# Nuxt3 - I can access page with params only from root directory

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vite

So, my pages directory looks like this.

```
pages
-board-[board]
--index.vue
-index.vue
```

And when I run dev server, if I go to '/' path and click a link to '/board-[board]' it works. But when if I directly go to '/board-[board]' path, server throws 500 Vite error.

I want to make that I can access from any path directly. What is the problem?

I couldn't do anything because the server only give 500 Vite error and code of the Vue page which caused error.